# Positioning sidebar widgets nicely under each other

Tags: html, css, layout, sidebar

We have a problem with a content-sidebar layout which breaks down to the following.

We have four divs, A, B, C and D. A and C have text and images - content - and should be placed on the left. B and D are lists of links, search forms, etc. - sidebar widgets - and should be placed on the right.

The divs have to appear in the order A, B, C, D in the HTML, because we'd like that to be the order on small screens. Like this, a set of quick links from the sidebar appears almost at the top, and the user doesn't have to scroll all the way down for that.

However, this gives us a problem with positioning on larger screens where we have a sidebar. Because the height of div B is lower than the height of div A, and div D has to come *after* div C, div D is positioned too low. See it for yourself in the below snippet. We'd like to have div D starting directly below div B.

We know the exact height of div A, but the other divs are flexible. The width of all divs is given. Is there a pure CSS way to make these divs position nicely? We'd rather not use JavaScript if not necessary. Naturally, this has to work cross-browser.

I thought about using CSS columns, but I need the sidebar to be less wide.

If there is a way to change the order of the elements for different screen sizes, that would work to. But I doubt that's possible without JavaScript.

```css
div#container {
  width: 100%;
}

div#container div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.left {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

div.right {
  float: right;
  width: 26%;
}

div#div-a {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
div#div-b {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
div#div-c {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0f0;
}
div#div-d {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div-a" class="left"></div>
  <div id="div-b" class="right"></div>
  <div id="div-c" class="left"></div>
  <div id="div-d" class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (remove `float: right` and use `display: inline-block` and 20px left margin for `.right`):

```css
div.right {
    /* float: right; */
    width: 26%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```